# Javascript ternary operator

Tags: javascript

I am creating two different icons for a google map. 
however only one icon appears.
a drop down select called facility will allow one icon based on a value of '8', all other values create the other icon.

```
var marker = createMarker(latlng, name, address, city, state, zipcode, telephone, images, url, facility);


function createMarker(latlng, name, address, city, state, zipcode, telephone, images, url, facility) { 
  var html = "<div id='infodiv'>" + name + "<br/><h4>" + address + "<br/>" + city + ", " + state + " " + zipcode + "<br/>" + (formatPhone(telephone)) + "</h4><div class='infoimage'><img src='" + images + "'></div><div class='footer'><a href='http://" + url + "'>" + url + "</a></div></div>";
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    icon: icon2,
    icon: (facility == 8) ? icon : icon, 
    map: map, 
    position: latlng 
  });
```

here are the icons:

```
var icon = new google.maps.MarkerImage("./images/plum_flag.png", 
new google.maps.Size(35, 52), new google.maps.Point(0, 0), 
new google.maps.Point(0, 52));
//callup the orange icon
var icon2 = new google.maps.MarkerImage("./images/orange_flag.png", 
new google.maps.Size(26, 39), new google.maps.Point(0, 0), 
new google.maps.Point(0, 39));
```

The only icon showing up is the 'var icon = new google.maps.MarkerImage("./images/plum_flag.png",' no matter what the select option is....

Comment: is it a typo in the question that you have `icon : icon` or is that what you have in the code. If that is not a typo in the question, I would guess that is your issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
(facility == 8) ? icon : icon,
```

means: if `facility` is `8`, use `icon`, otherwise use `icon`. Not very useful because it *always* uses `icon`.

Instead you might want:

```
(facility == 8) ? icon : icon2,
```

You might be confused that `icon` refers to the previous `icon: icon2` as you set. However, both `icon`s refer to the exact same thing so you won't see any difference.

Since you are defining `icon` with the ternary operator, the first `icon:` definiton can also be omitted (the second `icon:` definition is overwriting it anyway).

Answer (score 2):

This is wrong:

```
  icon: icon2,
  icon: (facility == 8) ? icon : icon,
```

You're assigning icon twice and in the second case, its the same thing in both cases.